# setting locally TOC depth

Tags: table-of-contents

Suppose I have 2 parts and I don't want to display for each of them the same level of details in the TOC. Is it possible to set the TOC's depth differentially ?

UPDATE : here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{Specifying locally TOC depth}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\subsection{subsection}

\part{second part}
\chapter{second chapter}
\section{second section}
\subsection{subsection}


\end{document}
```

What I want for instance is that the TOC of the first part shows chapter, section and subsection and the second part only chapter, section. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with a `MWE` with a `screenshot`? for easy understanding...

Comment: @MadyYuvi thank you for your remark, I updated my post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2 that should work as is should provide more functionality for toc depth per section.

Found here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure

Comment: thank you very much - it worked perfect